# Randomly generating floats spanning the whole spectrum of valid floats

Tags: java, random, java-7

As part of [random testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_testing), I'm looking to generate random floats spanning the whole spectrum of valid floats (but excluding +/- infinity and `NaN`). I want very, very large numbers and minuscule numbers, both positive and negative.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
Random r = new Random();
float random_value = (r.nextFloat() - 0.5f) * Float.MAX_VALUE;
```

This seems like it should *in theory* work, but it only generates very large values. (ie. in the range of 10<sup>37</sup> – 10<sup>38</sup>, positive and negative)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure if it's doable in your case, but you might be interested in http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/01/27/theres-only-four-billion-floatsso-test-them-all/

Comment: Interesting. Not doable, because I need a combination of 8 floats, and 4 billion^8 is not doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should create uniformly distributed `float` values, that is, a uniform distribution in a purely mathematical sense.  However, most of these values will be in the 10<sup>37</sup>-10<sup>38</sup> range, simply because there are more mathematical values in that range than in the lower, everyday value range.  In the real domain, there are 10 times as many values in the range 10<sup>37</sup>-10<sup>38</sup> as 10<sup>36</sup>-10<sup>37</sup>, 10 times as many values in the range 10<sup>36</sup>-10<sup>37</sup> as 10<sup>35</sup>-10<sup>36</sup>, and so on, so it's no surprise that just about all of them are of extremely large magnitude.

What I think you want is a completely random `float` value, with a range only in the *valid* `float` domain.  Because a `float` is specified by an exponent and a mantissa, the limiting factor as to how many values are available in a given range is limited by the precision, not how many mathematical values are available.  Specifically, there are precisely the same number of `float` values between `a` and `b` as there are between `2 * a` and `2 * b`, provided all values are within the `float` domain.

There is a one-to-one correspondence between all possible `int` values and all possible `float` values (including infinities and `NaN`), because both primitive types are represented by 32 bits.

Choose a random `int` value, across all possible `int` values, positive, 0, and negative, and convert the *bit representation* of the `int` to the corresponding *bit representation* of the `float` you want.  You'll have to choose a random `long` and downcast to `int`.  If you randomly get an infinity or an `NaN`, try again.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
float randomFloat = 0.0f;
do {
   // downcast will cover negative int value range.
   int randomInt = (int) rnd.nextLong(1L << 32); 

   float randomFloat = Float.intBitsToFloat(randomInt);
   // Discard infinities and NaNs.
} while (randomFloat == Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY ||
         randomFloat == Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY ||
         Float.isNaN(randomFloat));
```

Comment: Both a great explanation and a solution. Thank you.

Comment: What's the argument to `nextLong()`? `nextLong()` doesn't take an argument and seems your solution would work just fine without it.

Comment: Also, shouldn't `int randomInt = r.nextInt();` work? I read your comment but don't understand it.

Comment: Yes, `nextInt()` should fine, I had forgotten about that particular method.  It can produce all 2^32 possible values.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an uniform distribution by generating your floats using bits instead of arithmetic.

This could be an option:

```
public static float randomFloat() {
    // Generate a random integer. These are uniform over the 32 bit words
    Random r = new Random();
    int intBits = r.nextInt();

    // Make a float from the integer's bits
    float f = Float.intBitsToFloat(intBits);

    // Handle non-numeric cases
    if (Float.isInfinite(f) || Float.isNaN(f)) {
        // Only happens ~ 1/250 times
        return randomFloat();
    } else {
        return f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably hitting precision issues. Try doing the multiplication at double precision and then casting down to a float afterwards.

i.e.

```
float random_value = (float)((r.nextDouble() - 0.5) * Float.MAX_VALUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you want to generate a random float between -1 and 1. To do this:

```
Random r = new Random();
float random_value = r.nextFloat() * 2 - 1
```

and then scale that:

```
Random r = new Random();
float random_value = (r.nextFloat() * 2 - 1) * Float.MAX_VALUE
```